# Python String Conversion Json

Tags: python, json

I'v got a python script it gives me an error and I can't work it out. Here is my first bit of code to give you an understanding of what I am doing here

```
orders = cexapi.current_orders('GHS/NMC')  
print(orders)
```

this code runs fine and prints

```
[{u'price': u'2.1', u'amount': u'0.00000100', u'time': u'1395628131986', u'type': u'buy', u'id': u'567638429', u'pending': u'0.00000100'}]
```

I am trying to extract 567638429 after order id but it give me an error

```
ord = json.loads(orders['id'])  
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

This is the code I used to try and filter result.

```
orders = cexapi.current_orders('GHS/NMC')   
ord = json.loads(orders['id'])  
print(ord)
```

Comment: The library I am using is https://github.com/matveyco/cex.io-api-python/blob/master/cexapi.py

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the library you are using. But orders is a list with just one element, and the one element is a dictionary. This is why the print out or orders is enclosed in the [].

```
ord = json.loads(orders[0]['id']
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the return-value from .current_orders is already decoded, you shouldn't need to json.loads() it, just index into it to grab the value you want.

```
orders = cexapi.current_orders('GHS/NMC')
id = orders[0]['id']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a list:

```
[{u'price': u'2.1', u'amount': u'0.00000100', u'time': u'1395628131986', u'type': u'buy', u'id': u'567638429', u'pending': u'0.00000100'}]
```

By writing `orders[n]` you access the n-th element of this list. Obviously n must be a positive integer (and should not exceed the numbers of elements in the list).

Try `orders[0]['id']` instead.

`orders[0]` returns the first element of the list and `['id']` is then used as you did before.